# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'

Tags: php, mysql

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 in C:\AppServ\www\phpdemo\newssave.php on line 7

```
<?php 
    include"setup.php";

    $anonym=$_Post["anonym"];
    $sub=$_Post["sub"];
    $content=$_Post["content"];

    $sql= "insert into $newstable values('id','$anonym','$sub','$content');";
    $connect= mysql_connect($DB_SERVER,$DB_USER,$DB_PASS)or die("CONNECT WORNG");
    $db=mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$connect)or die("WORNG");
    $query= mysql_query($sql,$connect)or die("CONNECT WORNG");

    if(!$query) {
        print "POST ERROR";
    }
    else {
      print "post *** ok!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Your PHP code should work fine, the issue seems to be with MySQL server.

Comment: And please show us `setup.php`. Also use `$_POST` with capital letters.

Comment: What are the values of `$newstable` and `$DB_SERVER` ?